# How can I install iOS 7 on my 4th gen iPod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

Is it possible to get iOS 7 for the 4<sup>th</sup> generation iPod touch?

I tried to look it up online but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4):

No, iOS 7 is not compatible with the 4<sup>th</sup> generation iPod touch.

[image: iOS 7 is compatible with…]